# How to remove clutter / overlap in x-axis labels with pylab in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

We have the following OrderedDictionary saved in `d`:

```
OrderedDict([('CAT-QuickHeal', 328),
             ('TheHacker', 328),
             ('K7AntiVirus', 328),
             ('F-Prot', 328),
             ('BitDefender', 328),
             ('ViRobot', 328),
             ('McAfee-GW-Edition', 328),
             ('Jiangmin', 328),
             ('Fortinet', 328),
             ('SUPERAntiSpyware', 328),
             ('VBA32', 328),
             ('AVG', 328),
             ('McAfee', 327),
             ('Avast', 327),
             ('ClamAV', 327),
             ('Kaspersky', 327),
             ('Comodo', 327),
             ('F-Secure', 327),
             ('DrWeb', 327),
             ('Emsisoft', 327),
             ('Microsoft', 327),
             ('AhnLab-V3', 327),
             ('nProtect', 326),
             ('Malwarebytes', 326),
             ('VIPRE', 326),
             ('Symantec', 326),
             ('NANO-Antivirus', 326),
             ('Sophos', 326),
             ('ESET-NOD32', 326),
             ('GData', 326),
             ('Panda', 326),
             ('K7GW', 325),
             ('MicroWorld-eScan', 324),
             ('Ikarus', 324),
             ('Qihoo-360', 320),
             ('AegisLab', 319),
             ('Rising', 319),
             ('Ad-Aware', 319),
             ('Kingsoft', 318),
             ('CMC', 317),
             ('Tencent', 316),
             ('Cyren', 315),
             ('Zoner', 315),
             ('Zillya', 314),
             ('Avira', 314),
             ('AVware', 310),
             ('Arcabit', 309),
             ('ALYac', 301),
             ('TrendMicro', 299),
             ('Yandex', 298),
             ('Baidu', 294),
             ('TrendMicro-HouseCall', 288),
             ('Bkav', 279),
             ('Antiy-AVL', 265),
             ('Not Detected', 264),
             ('Invincea', 250),
             ('TotalDefense', 250),
             ('CrowdStrike', 239),
             ('Webroot', 219),
             ('ZoneAlarm', 216),
             ('Endgame', 192),
             ('Paloalto', 176),
             ('SentinelOne', 171),
             ('Alibaba', 45),
             ('Baidu-International', 31),
             ('Agnitum', 28),
             ('ByteHero', 27),
             ('Norman', 19),
             ('AntiVir', 13),
             ('Commtouch', 12),
             ('WhiteArmor', 9),
             ('PCTools', 7),
             ('eSafe', 5),
             ('VirusBuster', 2),
             ('NOD32', 2),
             ('eTrust-Vet', 2),
             ('Prevx', 2),
             ('Avast5', 2),
             ('SymantecMobileInsight', 1),
             ('Authentium', 1),
             ('Sunbelt', 1)])
```

`type(d)` gives `collections.OrderedDict`

We plot it as follows:

```
dictlist = []
for key, value in d.items():
    temp = [key,value]
    dictlist.append(temp)

x = []; y = []
for pair in dictlist:
    x.append(pair[0])
    y.append(pair[1])
r = range(81)
pl.xticks(r, x)
pl.xticks(r, x, rotation=90)
pl.plot(r,y,'*')
pl.show()
```

Resulting plot

[image: resulting plot]

We wish to remove the overlap between x-axis labels. Alternatively, is there a better way to plot this dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the figure size and also use tight_layout() for better plot. you can use d.keys and d.values to get the keys and values.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
pl.figure(num=None, figsize=(10, 6), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
pl.bar(range(len(d.keys())), d.values())
pl.xticks(range(len(d.values())), d.keys(), rotation=90)
pl.tight_layout()
pl.show()
```

will result in

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That works. One last thing: is there a way to produce bar lines instead of points or ticks in this graph?  For example, a bar line that stand over the x-label = 'CAT-Quickheal' and goes up to 328 on Y-axis.